# Java Method for removing duplicates from char array

Tags: java, arrays, char, duplicates

I have a char array filled by the user (`arrayInput[]`) with some characters, like {b, d, a, b, f, a, g, a, a, f}, and I need to create a method which returns a new char array with only the first occurrence of the character, but in the order of input. The book also says "A way to solve this problem is to create a boolean array to keep track of the characters to mantain!", but I can't imagine how the boolean array should work with the other arrays.

The main problem is that I can save in a boolean array if `arrayInput` contains a specific character, and even how many times, but only creating a very long ramified if-else into a for, like

```
    if ((arrayOutput[i] == 'A') && (arrayControl[0] = false)) {
        arrayControl[0] = true;  }
```

where `arrayOutput` is the array I want to return from the method, `arrayControl[0]` is the value of 'A' in my boolean array I created into the method. A = 0, B = 1, ... Z = 25, a = 26, b = 27, ... 51 = z. For every single character, uppercase and lowercase, I created a place into the array, so I could check everything, but now I can't go any further. I don't know how to save the characters on `arrayOutput`, how to check if a character is already on `arrayOutput` and if it's already there, the array passes that specific character and go to the next one.

Also please remember I'm a newbie, so I know very little about Java. Please explain yourself the best you can. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint for using the boolean array: Do not check for `false`. Instead check for `true` and remove the character from the array if the value is already `true` when you're visiting it.

Comment: True that! I'll save the tip on the book, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

### This could work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    char[] array = {'e','a','b','a','c','d','b','d','c','e'};
    main.getCharArray(array);
}

private char[] getCharArray(char[] array) {
    String _array = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(_array.indexOf(array[i]) == -1) // check if a char already exist, if not exist then return -1
            _array = _array+array[i];      // add new char
    }
    return _array.toCharArray();
}
```

### Output:

eabcd

Comment: Does the job but in `O(n^2)` other solutions offer `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 boolean arr[26]; //considering only small letters arrive. otherwise take a larger array.
for( i=0;i<str.length;i++ )
  arr[str[i]-'a']=true;
```

The ones at last after the loop are true are the actual character. (all duplicates eleminated).

To take into consideration the positions,

```
int arr[26];
  //initialize all the array elemnts to 0
  for( i=0;i<str.length();i++ )
      if(i>=arr[str[i]-'a'])
            arr[str[i]-'a']=i+1;
```

//Those greater than 0 are non-duplicated characters. Their poistion of first occurence= (arr[i]-1)

EDIT: I have last used java almost a year ago. The algorithm is shown properly. Sorry for my awkward java code.

Comment: This does not take into consideration the order of input.

Comment: @AnindyaDutta  Okay then we can instead of take an array of ints and the position can be put there.

Comment: @AnindyaDutta.: Now check my answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Make a separate array and store only non-duplicate characters.

```
char[] removeDuplicates (char[] arrayInput) {
    boolean exists[]=new boolean[26];
    char arrayOutput[] = new char[26];
    int ctr=0;
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++) {
        exists[i] = false;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<arrayInput.length; i++) {
        if(!exists[arrayInput[i]-97]) {
            exists[arrayInput[i]-97]=true;
            arrayOutput[ctr++]=arrayInput[i];
        }
    }

   return Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayOutput, 0, ctr);

}
```

Comment: In the second `for`, intially all values are `false`. Then whenever it encounters a new character, I update the position to `true`. 'a' represents `exists[0]`... `z` represents `exists[25]`. Then the next time, since it is `true`, the duplicate character will be skipped.

Comment: Oh. Ok. I couldn't even guess it, really. Maybe I'm missing something, but...why -97, and why !exists?

Comment: `-97` because I want to put `a` at position `0`. The Unicode value for `a` is 97. So to put a character `97` at position `0`, I subtract 97.
`!exists` because if the character already exists in the array, then we are definitely encountering a duplicate at this point and we must **not** consider it, and hence skip the loop for that character.

Comment: OH! Now I get it! And what if I don't want to use "(!exists[arrayInput[i]-97])" but another condition to say the same thing. How can I do? I need to ask this because I should use only what the book gave me, and that's an advanced level for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider using of collection framework then it would be much easier. Your array of `char` with duplicate is `arrayInput`. Now put each `char` from it to a `HashSet` like this -

```
HashSet<Character> uniqueCharSet = new HashSet<Character>();
for(char each : arrayInput){

   uniqueCharSet.add(each);
}
```

Now the `HashSet` `uniqueCharSet` will contains only the unique characters from the `char` array `arrayInput`. Note here all element in `uniqueCharSet` are wrapper type - `Character`.

You can convert the `HashSet` `uniqueCharSet` to array of `Character` like this -

```
Object[] uniqueCharArray = uniqueCharSet.toArray();
```

And then you can use them like this -

```
for(Object each : uniqueCharArray){
   Character c = (Character) each;
   System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sadly I can't use it. I'm allowed to use only for, if-else, while, do-while, arrays, methods, and the really basics of Java. I'm at the first year of university, and that's an exercise from the chapter about Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method to achieve what you need:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] arr= {'A','B','C','A','B'};

    HashSet<Character> hset=new HashSet<Character>();

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        hset.add(arr[i]);
        }

    Object[] ObjChar=hset.toArray();

    char[] resultArr = new char[ObjChar.length];

    for(int j=0;j<ObjChar.length;j++) {

    resultArr[j]=(char) ObjChar[j];
    }

    for(char eachChar: resultArr) {

        System.out.println(eachChar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow! When you answer a question, you have to explain what your code do. Thank you for your contribution.